# Can history files be unified in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I routinely run multiple `screen` sessions on my Linux desktops and servers.

A problem with this is that when I `grep` through my command history, I find I issued a command in a different session, and have to detach and re-attach to get that history item.

Is it possible to 'force' the differently-updated histories from multiple sessions to all go to a central history?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue whereby I was not able to view history between terminal sessions. Turns out my ~/.bash_history file was owned by root and not writable. Changing owner/group to my user fixed the issue: sudo chown <user>:<group> ~/.bash_history

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103944/real-time-history-export-amongst-bash-terminal-windows/3055135#3055135

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Insert the command `shopt -s histappend` in your `.bashrc`. This will append to the history file instead of overwriting it.
2. Also in your `.bashrc`, insert `PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND;history -a; history -n"` and the history file will be re-written and re-read each time bash shows the prompt.

EDIT: Thanks to e-t172 for the `history -n` trick

Comment: Thanks for this. I improved it further using PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND;history -a; 
history -n". This way, commands issued in other sessions immediately appear in the history of the current session (well, you need to press Enter first to update the history).

Comment: I didn't have `PROMPT_COMMAND` defined previously, so I had to use `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n"` to avoid errors.

Comment: please see the http://superuser.com/a/734410/250287 answer for the correct history -a, -c, and -r commands.

Comment: Just an alert to the newcomer: after using history rewriting for a while, I realized that I was often issuing the wrong commands; when you see in the previous line some command, you expect up arrow to repeat it, and with this config it is no longer always the case.

Answer (score 17):

Please don't use `history -a; history -n`, it does not work as you expect and will leave you with many duplicate, out of order commands in your history. A solution that works generally as expected is the following:

```
# unified bash history
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

Using a newline instead of a semicolon is also a short way of dealing with the missing/duplicate semicolon problem with PROMPT_COMMAND.

Comment: history -a, -c, and then -r is correct...this should be the accepted answer

Comment: The `export` is not necessary. Because interactive shell options are supposed to be set from `~/.bashrc` which is called from every sub shell, so inheritance is not necessary.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to just use `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` instead?

Comment: That ordering would require one to store the last exit value before running the history commands, since many prompt commands rely on or display it.

Comment: This generally works but does have an interesting functionality, namely that you've got to ask for `history` twice before getting the fully updated history included commands from other windows.

Comment: why does it work in the fashion @jeremy_rutman say?

Comment: You don't need to run the command twice - you simply need to run _any_ command (or no command) for the PROMPT_COMMAND callback to execute and update the history for your current session. Then running `history` will display the synchronized history. You can easily deduce why this is the case by looking at the statements that are executed as part of the PROMPT_COMMAND.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solution here worked for me, but what did work was just using:

```bsh
cat ~/.bash_history | grep something
```

instead of

```bsh
history | grep something
```

Kudos to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32913509/2750743) SO answer.

Answer (score -1):

PROMPT_COMMAND is not defined by default in some distros. For example, it is defined in Arch, but not in Debian.

I have a bashrc in my Dropbox that I use while distro hopping, and it includes:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$( [ '$PROMPT_COMMAND' ] && echo $PROMPT_COMMAND; )history -a; history -n"
```

Comment: An awful solution to a basic shell programming problem. The right way: ```PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND; history -a; history -n"```

Comment: Better: `PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND"$'\n''history -a; history -n'`