# How can I see Bash history from more than one terminal session in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can history files be unified in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/37576/can-history-files-be-unified-in-bash)

I use Ubuntu Server 9.10 and I would like to be able to see my bash history for more than one terminal sessions. I.e. my last 200 commands or so, even if I have been logged out in between.

When I use the `history` I just see all commands from my actual terminal session. How can I see more command history from Bash? Is there any specific settings for bash that I should change from the default values in Ubuntu?

I don't have a `~/.bash_history` file. But I have an `~/.bashrc` with `HISTCONTROL=$HISTCONTROL${HISTCONTROL+,}ignoredups` and `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth`

```
echo $HISTFILE
/home/sanoj/.bash_history
echo $HISTSIZE
500
echo $HISTFILESIZE
500
echo $HISTCONTROL
ignoreboth
```

---

**UPDATE:** I am now trying Ubuntu Server 10.10 in VirtualBox. If I just turn off VirtualBox without the shutdown command, then next time when I boot, the commands from the last session is not saved in the history file.

The commands are only saved if I shutdown the machine with the shutdown command. E.g. shutdown -P 0.

This must be the reason to my problem. So I have to figure out how to save the command-history more often. E.g. after each command.

Comment: What do you get if you do `echo $HISTSIZE` and `echo $HISTFILESIZE` ? My (Ubuntu) `~/.bashrc` has the same `HISTCONTROL` lines as yours which is brain dead since the second one overrides the first and the values are supposed to be colon-separated, not comma-separated. If you do `set -o` does it show a line that says "history on"?

Comment: I get `500` with `echo` on both variables and `history on`

Comment: the second *HISTCONTROL* statement is the one you're getting, not the first.  though *ignoreboth* is bash shorthand for *ignoredups* + *ignorespace* so that probably isn't the issue.

Comment: What do these commands give you? `echo $BASH_VERSION` and `shopt | grep hist` and `set -o | grep hist` and `strings $(type -p bash) | grep -i history_ | grep -i enable`

Comment: this is a duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/37576/can-history-files-be-unified-in-bash

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/37576/can-history-files-be-unified-in-bash/37583#37583

Comment: @warren: nice find.  i agree, looks like exactly what Sanoj is asking for.

Comment: **Asked again:** [How to get a persistent “history”-file even after a non-clean shutdown?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/how-to-get-a-persistent-history-file-even-after-a-non-clean-shutdown)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
history -a
```

to immediately append the in-memory history to the history file. One terminal session can't see another's unless this is done or the other is exited.

You can use

```
history 200 | less
```

to see that number of entries.

In addition to `HISTSIZE` see the entry in the Bash man page concerning `HISTFILESIZE`.

Comment: `history -a´ doesn't do anything for me, and not `history 200 | less` either, but I have updated my question with more info. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think that I have found a reason now. The history is not saved unless I do a clean shutdown. See my new question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/how-to-get-a-persistent-history-file-even-after-a-non-clean-shutdown

Answer (score 8):

Once you log out the history gets appended to the file `~/.bash_history`. Have a look in there.

By default it will remember your last 500 commands. If you want to save more set the variable `HISTSIZE` in `~/.bashrc`.

I also do add `ignoredups` to `HISTCONTROL` (with `HISTCONTROL=$HISTCONTROL:ignoredup`). This makes duplicate consecutive commands to be save only once.

Have a look at `man 1 bash` for what else you can tune about the history.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't have an `~/bash_history` file, and no `HISTSIZE` in `~/.bashrc` but I have `HISTCONTROL=$HISTCONTROL${HISTCONTROL+,}ignoredups` and `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` and It is Ubuntu Server, if that matter.

Comment: @Snoj Notice the `.` in `~/.bash_history`. And for `HISTSIZE` it will just use the default value of 500 entries.

Comment: Yes, but I have no `~/.bash_history` file on my system. I used `ls -a` to check.

Comment: @Sanoj So maybe it is not the default. The filename is stored in the `$HISTFILE` variable, so `echo $HISTFILE` will tell you where to look.

Comment: `echo $HISTFILE` gives me `/home/sanoj/.bash_history` - strange. Maybe it's not activated by security reasons?

Comment: This is very puzzling and doesn't make too much sense. Are you sure you can reproduce this on a clean and fresh system?

Comment: I think that I have found a reason now. The history is not saved unless I do a clean shutdown. See my new question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/how-to-get-a-persistent-history-file-even-after-a-non-clean-shutdown

Answer (score 1):

bash history is usually loaded when the shell begins running, and is saved when it is exited normally. You can use `history -a` and `history -n` to override this, but not automatically unless you abuse `$PROMPT_COMMAND` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Sanoj, this really should "just work"; I don't think there is supposed to be anything special you need to do to enable this.  It sounds like something is interfering with the normal course of events.

I would look in /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc (or perhaps /etc/bash.bashrc according to some sources), ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_login, ~/.bash_logout, to see if there is anything that might be affecting the history (perhaps `grep -i hist` on each of the above files).

... In particular I wonder if you have something in ~/.bash_logout that removes the file.

Alternatively, is it possible that something is overriding the `$HOME` variable?